# В чём разница, между методами класса Object, отвечающими за многопоточность и методами интерфейса Condition?

Tags: java, многопоточность, объекты, condition

Про методы интерфейса `Condition` сказано:

- `await`: поток ожидает, пока не будет выполнено некоторое условие и пока другой поток не вызовет методы `signal()` / `signalAll()`. Во многом аналогичен методу `wait()` класса `Object`
- `signal`: сигнализирует, что поток, у которого ранее был вызван метод `await()`, может продолжить работу. Применение аналогично использованию методу `notify()` класса `Object`
- `signalAll`: сигнализирует всем потокам, у которых ранее был вызван метод `await()`, что они могут продолжить работу. Аналогичен методу `notifyAll()` класса `Object`

https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/8.10.php

Хотелось бы узнать, в чём разница между методами класса `Object` и интерфейса `Condition` и в каких случаях нужно применять одни, а в каких другие

Comment: Ну во-первых Condition - это интерфейс.

Comment: Самая полезная часть интерфейса `Condition`, ИМХО, это возможность ограничить время ожидания: методы `awaitNanos` и `awaitUntil`